# como soluciono abro Nemo no abre ni reinstalandolo en linuxmint 21?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

Ya he intentado reinstalandolo. Desisintalando cinnamon y volviendolo a instalar y nada.

No abre, ni tampoco aparecen los iconos del escritorio.

Nemo es el gestor de archivos predeterminado de cinnamon.

Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

> System:   Kernel: 5.15.0-47-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon
> 5.4.11
> Distro: Linux Mint 21 Vanessa

imprimo la salida del comando nemo nemo --debug

> (nemo:63531): GLib-DEBUG: 22:01:41.845: unsetenv() is not
> thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
> (nemo:63531): Gtk-DEBUG: 22:01:41.845: Connecting to session manager
> (nemo:63531): Gtk-DEBUG: 22:01:41.847: Failed to get the GNOME screensaver proxy: The name org.gnome.ScreenSaver is not owned
> (nemo:63531): Gtk-DEBUG: 22:01:41.847: Registering client 'org.Nemo' ''
> (nemo:63531): Gtk-DEBUG: 22:01:41.849: Registered client at '/org/gnome/SessionManager/Client27'
> (nemo:63531): GLib-GIO-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/preferences/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/window-state/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/icon-view/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/list-view/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/compact-view/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/desktop/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/sidebar-panels/tree/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/plugins/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/preferences/menu-config/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/nemo/search/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/lockdown/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/background/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/media-handling/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/applications/terminal/" (establishing: 0,
> active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.852: watch_fast: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/privacy/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_fast: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 0, active: 0)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/preferences/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/window-state/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/icon-view/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/list-view/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/compact-view/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/desktop/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/gtk/settings/file-chooser/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/sidebar-panels/tree/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/plugins/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/preferences/menu-config/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/nemo/search/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.853: watch_established: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/lockdown/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.854: watch_established: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/background/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.854: watch_established: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/media-handling/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.854: watch_established: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/applications/terminal/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.854: watch_established: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/privacy/" (establishing: 1)
> (nemo:63531): dconf-DEBUG: 22:01:41.854: watch_established: "/org/cinnamon/desktop/interface/" (establishing: 1)
>
> ```
> ** (nemo:63531): WARNING **: 22:01:41.869: Current gtk theme is not known to have nemo support (Adapta-Nokto) - checking...
> Violación de segmento (`core' generado)
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos el error se debe a que use la aplicacion systemback para la instalacion del sistema.

actualmente systemback no es compatible con ubuntu 20.04 y 22.04. no soporta el sistema de archivos moderno de estas distribuciones.

si ejecutamos `ls -l /bin /lib /lib32 /lib64 /libx32 /sbin` veremos que no crea los enlances simbolicos del sistema.

Aun asi si usamos un entorno como xfce es posible no notar los daños. En Cinnamon deja de funcionar el escritorio y nemo;tengo entendido que caja en mate tambien se afecta...

En fin si deseamos crear una iso personalizada apartir de nuestro sistema lo mas recomendable es no usar ubuntu/linuxmint(hasta que arreglen systemback).

Mxlinux21 Kde se puede personalizar muy bien para que funcione muy parecido a cinnamon y nos permite crear una iso instalable del sistema aun por encima de los 4GB e incluso puedes cambiar dolphin por nemo si gustas.

Advertencia: es un poco liosa la instalaccion del driver nvidia-340 en mxlinux21 porque debian dice que hay fallas en la seguridad y lo ha excluido. Aun asi, desde el instalador descargado de la web es posible aunque no lo he probado con exito.